# Zendesk API: Receiving 422 response with "Email: cannot be blank"

Tags: php, api, postman, guzzle, zendesk

when using postman, everything works fine as per screenshot below:

[image: postman request]

Once guzzle client is used, for the same payload (visible in screenshot below), there is this error message "email cannot be blank":

[image: guzzle payload]

In the documentation, I don't see anything regarding email needed and if it is, then why am I able to create from postman in the first place?

What has been done so far:

1. Including "email" into the payload as a part of "request" key,
2. Including inside "comment"
3. Add it outside of "request" key in the payload

None of them worked.

The full error message is:

```
"{
    "error":"RecordInvalid",
    "description":"Record validation errors",
    "details":{
                "email":[
                 {   
                    "description":"Email: cannot be blank",
                    "error":"BlankValue"
                 }
              ]
            }
  }"
```

Does anyone has an idea what could be the solution?

EDIT:

When I try directly using postman it works and I don't have `email` in the request at all.

[image: postman request]

EDIT #2:

[image: postman auth]

Comment: welcome to so, also tell about auth of the api you are trying to fetch, or show description of api you are requesting

Comment: I'm using basic auth, which is basically `email/token:secret`

Comment: show your authorization screenshot(you can hide the data) on postman

Comment: Do you need 'json' =>[], i think it works without the json wrap.

Comment: @Grumpy it is need for sending payload as application\json

Comment: @subject110011 show your guzzle code as well

Comment: Payload is already attached, the rest is just sending like `$response = $this->guzzleClient->request(
            Request::METHOD_POST,
            self::URL,
            $payload
        );`

Comment: are you sure that your $this->config['username'] returns you the required value I checked the [docs of the api](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/ticket-requests/) you are using and they say to add email of end user as username

Comment: Yes, it is my email address that I'm using for the non-guzzle request... So if I am able to use this in postman request, I don't get why would it not work with guzzle client.